# Get count form reations [Laravel 5]

Tags: laravel-5, belongs-to

I have realation like this below...

```
public function likesXp()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Like', 'comment_like')
                ->withPivot('user_id')
                ->where('like_id',1)
                ->selectRaw('count(comment_like.like_id) as aggregate');
    }
```

How can I get `aggregate` count from this relation?

I need to do something like this:

```
return Model::with('likesXp')->where('comments.user_id',1)->get()->aggregate;
```

Comment: does [->count()](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#aggregates) not work?

Comment: There is a `count` function that you can use. See `Using Aggregate Methods` on the linked documentation. Or am I missunderstanding something?

Comment: I know for that method but I need count from all relations...